# Is there different between google sign in and sign up

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I am having a trouble with "**Sign in**" to the `google account`  in "**Sign Up**" I am using

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Log.d("activity2", "email:" + user.getEmail() + "\n" + "photo_url" + user.getPhotoUrl() + "\n" + "user_name" + user.getDisplayName() + "\n" + "provider id" + user.getProviderId() + "\n" + "user id" + user.getUid() + "\n" + "token" + acct.getId()+" "+ acct.getIdToken() + "\ncredential" +credential);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "can not sign in,please use native sign in" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Sign in failed
                        Log.d("activity2", " not registered");
                    }
                }
            });
```

therefore I need to know **is the process same** for "sign in" ?

Comment: sign in same as log in, sign up mean sign up as a member

Answer (score 0):

**Sign in existing users**

> Create a new signIn method which takes in an email address and
>   password, validates them, and then signs a user in with the
>   signInWithEmailAndPassword method.

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

**Sign up new users**

> Create a new createAccount method which takes in an email address and
>   password, validates them and then creates a new user with the
>   createUserWithEmailAndPassword method.

```
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Add a form to register new users with their email and password and call this new method when it is submitted.

more details refer [Set up Firebase Authentication for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/)